# Let $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be defined as $g(x)=x^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$ and $g(0)=0$. Prove that $g^\prime$ is unbounded at $0$.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be defined as $g(x)=x^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$ and $g(0)=0$. Prove that $g$ is differentiable at $0$ and find $g^\prime(0)$.  Prove that $g^\prime$ is unbounded at $0$.

**Attempt at Solution**

I started with the limit definition of the derivative: $$g^\prime=\frac{g(0+h)-g(0)}{h}.$$

Plugging in the appropriate pieces for $g$, I get $g^\prime=\frac{h^2\sin(\frac{1}{x^2})-0}{h}=h\sin(\frac{1}{x^2})$. Letting $h\to0$, I get $g^\prime=\lim\limits_{h\to0} h\sin(\frac{1}{x^2})=0$. Thus, $g$ is differentiable at $0$, and $g^\prime(0)=0$.

I think this is right, but I don't know how to do the second part, proving that $g^\prime$ is unbounded at $0$.

Any help/hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Calculate the derivative $g'(x)$ and show what happens with $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} g'(x)$.

Comment: Do I just use the same method as before when finding $g^\prime(0)$?

Comment: $g'(x) = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$, or just use the product rule and chain rule.

Comment: Please not that the function is differentiable at x=0 but the derivative is not continuous at x=0. That is where the "unboundedness" comes from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well

$$x\neq 0\implies g'(x)=2x\sin\frac1{x^2}-\frac2{x}\cos\frac1{x^2}$$

Notice now that the first summand in the right expression above is very bounded around zero (in fact its limit is zero), yet the second one definitely is unbounded...

Comment: Why does the 2nd term have a cos?

Comment: Well, that's the derivative of sine after applying the product rule...

Comment: Oh god I feel stupid. I was thinking that I need to use the limit definition of the derivative again. Nevermind. Just brain melting.